# How can I insert into React's state array with setState?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm looking to modify and array in react and insert elements on specific index. This is how my state looks like:

```
this.state = {arr: ['', '', '', '' ]}
```

What I wanna do is to compile this `arr[index] = 'random element'` to react js setState syntax. What I tried to do was:

```
this.setState({ arr[index]: 'random element' })
```

but failed, ty!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

[image]

Clone the current state using `slice()`. By doing this, the original state remains unaffected till `setState()`. After cloning, do your operations over the cloned array and set it in the state. The previous answer will **mutate** the state. Read about this [here](https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c#.xtosqqg8w)

```
let a = this.state.arr.slice(); //creates the clone of the state
a[index] = "random element";
this.setState({arr: a});
```

Comment: Another way of creating a deep copy of an object, including arrays is to use the spread operator, as follows: `let myElmClone = {...this.state.myElm};`

Comment: Just here to say, despite having faced an issue in Vue JS, I stumbled upon state update related gotchas in Stencil. And this comment helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

use spread operator https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-the-spread-syntax-f5c35525f754

```
let newChild = "newChild"

this.setState({
    children: [
        ...this.state.children,
        newChild
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

Just use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object/30042948#30042948) to make a copy of your state.

Thus, you can do it as follows :

```
let new_state = Object.assign({}, this.state); 
let a = new_state.arr;
a[index] = "random element";
this.setState({arr: a});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, I should have gone deeper, that looks so easy and nice. Meanwhile I found a method as well, but this one is definitely the best way to do it, ty!

Comment: This is the bad way of implementing You should not mutate the state directly!

Comment: Agreed, `let a = this.state.arr;` is merely making another reference to the same array, which you can't mutate directly.

Comment: a is reference of the state arr. Which will cause strange behavior because you are changing its state on line 3. 
You should create a copy of the array on line 1 (not a reference of it)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this will work.

**State Array**

```
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState<string[]>([])
```

**Add to state array**

```
function onChangeArray(newValue: string) {
    setMyArray(myArray => [...myArray, newValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Two Ways to do:**

1. **Using concat** :

**NOTE:** It is not allowed to use the *array push method*, because it mutates the array. It doesn’t leave the array intact but changes it. Instead, there should be a new array created which is used to update the state.

*Array concat method* creates a new array, leaving the old array intact, but also returning a new array from it.

```
this.state = {
      value: '',
      list: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    };

this.setState(state => {
const list = state.list.concat(state.value);
return {
        list,
        value: '',
      };
});
```

2. **Using ...spread operator** :

```
this.state = {
      value: '',
      list: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    };

this.setState(state => {
const list = [...state.list, state.value]; <--insert in end -->``
const list = [state.value, ...state.list]; <--Or insert in start -->
return {
        list,
        value: '',
      };
});
```

***Reference*** : https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove/

Answer (score 1):

Immer is a common dependency to help with this kind of thing.  In this example, you would do something like

```js
import {useImmer} from "use-immer"

export default function MyComponent(props) {
   const [state, setState] = useImmer({arr: ['', '', '', '' ]})

   // .... some time later

   setState(draft => {
       draft.arr[index] = newValue
   })
}
```

And Immer will take care of making sure that your state is updated immutably and correctly.